# My code acts like it is on a while loop, even though its not

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to make it so it plays an alarm 15 times, after each as ended.
I expected it to work, and then print that it's finished. However, it prints it infinitely and it eventually freezes Roblox Studio.

I have researched and researched and the sound end event only fires when the sound ends, so its not the event firing multiple times. I didn't see an answer on StackOverFlow (as expected).

Here's my localscript:

```
-- 15 times
local warheadalarmevent = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("WarheadAlarm")
warheadalarmevent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 1st time
    script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
        script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 2nd time
        script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
            script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 3rd time
            script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 4th time
                script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                    script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 5th time
                    script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                        script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 6th time
                        script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                            script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 7th time
                            script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 8th time
                                script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                    script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 9th time
                                    script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                        script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 10th time
                                        script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                            script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 11th time
                                            script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                                script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 12th time
                                                script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                                    script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 13th time
                                                    script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                                        script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 14th time
                                                        script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                                            script.WarheadAlarm:Play() -- 15th time
                                                            script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
                                                                print("15 times")
                                                            end)
                                                        end)
                                                    end)
                                                end)
                                            end)
                                        end)
                                    end)
                                end)
                            end)
                        end)
                    end)
                end)
            end)
        end)
    end)
end)
```

Here is my Script (fires the remote event):

```
local alreadydone = false

function myfunction()
    if alreadydone == true then
        return
    end
    
    alreadydone = true

    script.Parent.Parent.Button.Transparency = 1
    script.Parent.Parent.FakeButton.Transparency = 0
    script.Parent.Parent.Button.ClickDetector.MaxActivationDistance = 0

    wait(.2)
    script.Parent.Parent.Button.Transparency = 0
    script.Parent.Parent.FakeButton.Transparency = 1
    game.ReplicatedStorage.WarheadAlarm:FireAllClients()
    game.Workspace.MordernTV.TV.SCREEN.SurfaceGui.Status.Text = "PRIMING"
    game.Workspace.MordernTV.TV.SCREEN.SurfaceGui.Status.TextColor3 = Color3.new(1, 1, 0)
    wait(30)
    game.Workspace.MordernTV.TV.SCREEN.SurfaceGui.Status.Text = "PRIMED, ENGAGING.."
    game.Workspace.MordernTV.TV.SCREEN.SurfaceGui.Status.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0, 1, 0)                      
end                            

script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:connect(myfunction)
```

I'm not clicking it multiple times or anything, what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

What is happening in your code is that you are connecting more and more and more and more listeners to the same event without ever disconnecting any of them. Every time the alarm plays, you connect another listener, as well as another function that connect more listeners. Studio crashes because you've created an infinite loop of functions that connect functions and eventually there are too many to process and Studio crashes.

Instead of connecting to the Sound.Ended signal, you can also call the signal's Wait() function which will yield the thread until the event happens. So you can use that inside a loop to make sure the alarms fire one after another and keep track of how many times the alarm has played.

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local warheadAlarm = script.WarheadAlarm
local warheadAlarmEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("WarheadAlarm")

-- create a debounce flag
local isAlarmPlaying = false

warheadAlarmEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    -- if alarm is already playing, escape
    if isAlarmPlaying then
        return
    end

    -- flip the debounce flag
    isAlarmPlaying = true

    -- play the alarm, and wait for each sound to finish
    local callCount
    for callCount = 0, 15, 1 do
        warheadAlarm:Play()
        warheadAlarm.Ended:Wait()
    end

    -- do the thing
    print("15 times")

    -- reset the debounce flag
    isAlarmPlaying = false
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer that I don't really know about Roblox, but I think this is a good guess, and I did read a little bit about it.)

When you connect a function to the ended event, it will be called every time the sound ends, not just the next time. After the first time, there will be multiple functions connected to the ended event, which you probably don't want. And, even after the 15th time, the first 14 connections are still there and trying to replay the sound (and playing the sound multiple times at once may also be bad and connecting more and more functions to the event could plausibly cause big problems pretty quickly as the number of connections grows exponentially).

This can probably be fixed by disconnecting each connection the first time it fires. But, it may be easier to just connect one function to the event and have a variable that counts up to 15 that determines whether to refire the sound. Then, if you want to potentially use the sound object again, I guess you should still disconnect the connection.

Untested:

```
warheadalarmevent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
  script.WarheadAlarm:Play()
  local n = 0
  local connection
  connection = script.WarheadAlarm.Ended:Connect(function()
    n = n + 1
    if n < 15 then
      script.WarheadAlarm:Play()
    else
      connection:Disconnect()
    end
  end)
end)
```

(Note the connection still presumably applies to anything trying to play `script.WarheadAlarm`, so if multiple things are trying to play this sound at the same time, you may need to further rethink your approach.)